# Бордер перемещаемый мышкой

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Хочу сделать кубик, который я бужу двигать по Canvas'у мышкой и после каждого переноса бордера в текст боксе выводило бы его конечные координаты относительно Canvas'а или окна приложения. Никак не могу отследить именно положение бордера в определенный момент времени, как бы это можно сделать?

Comment: А в чем вопрос?

Comment: @Арина забыл совсем :-З Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно поняла, для решения вашей проблемы можно отлавливать координаты через обработчик событий мыши.
(Приведу пример для события нажатия мыши и контейнера pictureBox1)

```
 private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point p1;
            p1.X = e.X;
            p1.Y = e.Y;
        }
```

Вы можете использовать другой контейнер и событие мыши, суть та же-получаем координаты от объекта класса `MouseEventArgs`.

Comment: У меня в MouseEventArgs нельзя обратиться к положению мыши(к X) я могу макс получить изменение этой координаты..